# Initializing list in sub class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use the constructor of an abstract class. I have to store a reference to a class `Swiat` in abstract class `Organizmy`. `Organizmy` has sub class `Zwierze` (which is an abstract class, too), then another sub class of `Zwierze`, `Czlowiek`. (`Organizmy` (abstract) >>> `Zwierze` (abstract) >>> `Czlowiek`).

I'm trying to initialize a list passing parameters to constructors. First in the `Czlowiek` class to the `Zwierze` constructor, then the `Zwierze` constructor pass args to the `Organizm` constructor.

This is my code:

Organizm.h

```
#pragma once
class Swiat;
class Organizm
{
public:
    Swiat& swiat;  //MY REFERENCE
    char symbol = '?';
    int sila = 0;
    int inicjatywa = 0;
    int* polozenie; //x y
    
    virtual void Akcja()=0;
    virtual void Kolizja()=0;
    virtual void Rysowanie()=0;
    Organizm(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int polozenie[2]);
```

Organizm.cpp

```
#include "Organizm.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Organizm::Rysowanie()
{
    cout << "Hej jestem organizmem" << endl;
}

Organizm::Organizm(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int* polozenie)
    :swiat(swiat), symbol(symbol), sila(sila), inicjatywa(inicjatywa), polozenie(polozenie) {}
```

Zwierze.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Organizm.h"
class Zwierze : public Organizm
{
public:
    void Akcja() override;
    void Kolizja() override;
    Zwierze(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int* polozenie);
};
```

Zwierze.cpp

```
#include "Zwierze.h"

using namespace std;

void Zwierze::Akcja()
{
    //todo
}
void Zwierze::Kolizja()
{
    //todo
}

Zwierze::Zwierze(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int* polozenie) : Organizm(swiat, symbol, sila, inicjatywa, polozenie) {}
```

Czlowiek.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Zwierze.h"

class Czlowiek : public Zwierze
{
public:
    //int polozenie[2];
    int* polozenie;
    Swiat& s;
    void Rysowanie() override;
    void Powiedz();
    Czlowiek(Swiat& swiat);
};
```

Czlowiek.cpp

```
#include "Czlowiek.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Czlowiek::Czlowiek(Swiat& swiat) : Zwierze(swiat, 'A', 5, 4, polozenie) {}
void Czlowiek::Rysowanie()
{
    cout << "Hej, jestem czlowiekiem"<<symbol << endl;
}
void Czlowiek::Powiedz()
{
    cout << "Mam tyle sily: " << sila << endl;
}
```

In `main()`, I just create `Swiat` object and in `Swiat` method is creating new `Czlowiek` object:

```cpp
Organizm* czlowiek = new Czlowiek(*this);
```

The error message I'm getting is

> "uninitialized reference member" (code block)

and

> "Czlowiek::s": "references must be initialized" (visual)

Comment: You need to initialize the member reference `Czlowiek::s` in the member initializer list of the constructor.

Comment: As the error message says you have not initialized the Czlowiek::s reference which is separate from the Organizm::swiat reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the member reference `Czlowiek::s` in the member initializer list of the constructor like this:

```
Czlowiek::Czlowiek(Swiat& swiat) :s(swiat), Zwierze(swiat, 'A', 5, 4, polozenie) {}
```

Comment: Yes, It works now for me, I missed my s variable in Czlowiek, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not initializing the `s` member of class `Czlowiek`. You probably want something like this.

```cpp
   Czlowiek::Czlowiek(Swiat& swiat) : Zwierze(swiat, 'A', 5, 4, polozenie), s{swiat} {}
```

Comment: Yes, It works now for me, I missed my s variable in Czlowiek, thanks!